# Usage of increment operators

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
int i=3,y;
y=++i*++i*++i;
    printf("%d",y);
}
```

The i value is initially getting incremented to 4.Then it is incremented to 5. therefore it is incremented to 6. accordingly result should come 216. but 150 is coming as a result.

Comment: It is really should be `216`.... So, perhaps, problem not in the code. Try rebuild the binary file, ro try different compiler (e.g. g++ insted of gcc)

Comment: There are quite a few post on SO about sequence points and undefined behavior. Look them up.

Comment: no g++ is also giving 150

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- It will execute like this;
- First it is considers like this,

  ```
  y = (++i * ++i) * ++i // so first i is incremented to 4 and again it will incremented to 5.
  ```
- So now first expression will executed like this

  ```
  y = (5 * 5) * ++i; 
  y = 25 * ++i;
  ```
- Now again i is incremented to 6 and final expression is like this,

  ```
  y = 25 * 6;
  y = 150;
  ```